# What is this CSS rule?

Tags: css

In the son of suckerfish drop down menu:

http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/

You see this rule

```
w\idth: 13.9em;
```

This can't be a typo as it appears various times in the css. What is it for?

Comment: @ozsenegal, that's no moon...uh, *mistake*.

Comment: ugh, using `ul` for menus instead of `menu`... what up with that? `menu` is a valid (deprecated) html 4 tag, and behaves like a `ul` by default. It's redefined and has a type attribute in html5 which allows for different display methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called a [CSS Hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter).

Some browser will ignore the `\` and treat that as a `width` property; other browsers will ignore the entire property.

You can see a complete list [here](http://centricle.com/ref/css/filters/?highlight_columns=true).

Answer (score 8):

It's called the [`Modified Box Model Hack`](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Box_Model_Hack#A_Modified_SBMH_.28Tan_hack.29).

From the linked site:

> as explained above in the section on the SBMH is hidden from IE5.x/Win because of the character escape. IE5/Mac and IE6/Win which implement the CSS box model correctly, therefore, properly get a width of 100px.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "box model hack" to workaround the [incorrect box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) for older IE versions.

Read more about this specific hack here: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Box_Model_Hack

Answer (score 0):

It likely has to do with the box model hack. Read here for more info: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aaboxmodelhack.htm